# How to check the date is modified in UIDatePicker or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, uidatepicker

I am using `UIDatePicker` to select a date. When loading the view **date picker minimum date** was set with **current date**, For my specification I need to know is there any modification done in `UIDatePicker` or not.

```
if ([[date_picker minimumDate] compare:[date_picker date]] != NSOrderedSame) {
  printf("value modified");
}
```

I  have tried with the above condition but its always not matching even though I have not modified the date. Am I doing anything wrong? How do I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

Set control events for datepicker like this

```
   [date_picker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(pickerChanged:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and in the pickerChanged method get its value

```
    - (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender{
             selectedDate=[sender date];
       }
```

date comparison with

```
    if ([initialDate compare:selectedDate]!=NSOrderedSame)
        {
           NSLog(@"modified");
         // two dates are same and the date formatting of the two dates must be same
        }
```

so whenever you change the date this method will be triggered initialDate is when the view loaded the value is set

Comment: Even if I revert the date back to original I should come to know, no modification in date.

Comment: just set a flag in the pickerChanged method and the pickerChanged method will get executed oly when the date changes when it reverts back to current date set the flag as false

Comment: thats what I am trying to do. but above condition is not matching for my case.

Comment: current date, when the view is loaded.

Comment: I have printed using date formatter both printing same date, but while comparing its not matching.

Comment: your code worked for me with a small change just see my edited answer

Comment: I have tried, Still no luck, I have been checking, I will update asap, thanks.